# datetime validations in a dropdown list PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I'm working on a validation in my dropdown list that contains values from my database. I can now view the values in the dropdown list but now I'm stuck with doing a validation on it. the values in the dropdown list are in datetime format e.g (2019-04-02 07:21:34).

Now, I have two of them dropdown list with a label "To:" and "From:" basically what i want to do is if I selected a date in the first dropdown list lets say 2019-02-02 and at the 2nd one i selected 2019-01-01 and when i press a button, it should not be valid because its in backwards and a message should appear that the dates i've entered are invalid. I'm confused on what to do because the format contains hyphens and colons.

```
<?php

  $hostname = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "";
  $databaseName = "it180p";

  $connect = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $databaseName);
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `incidentreport` ORDER BY dateTime DESC";


  $result1 = mysqli_query($connect, $query);


  $result2 = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

  $options = "";

  while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
  {
      $options = $options."<option>$row2[6]</option>";
  }

?>
        To:
        <select>
          <option disabled selected value> - select start of date - </option>
            <?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)):;?>          
            <option value="<?php echo $row1[0];?>"><?php echo $row1[6];?></option>
            <?php endwhile;?>
        </select>
        From:
        <select>
          <option disabled selected value> - select end of date - </option>
            <?php echo $options;?>
        </select>
```

Comment: Why are you making the exact same query twice? Why not reuse the data you got from the first query instead?

Comment: for some reason, If i only have one query, the other dropdown list does not get the values from the database

Comment: Then you did something wrong. Post that code and explain what happened instead, because making the query twice if very inefficient.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. Will try to fix it once I'm done with this one

Answer (score 1):

Include js, and call change event on any dropdown.
First of all Assign ids to your dropdowns "from_date" and "to_date".

When ever value from any drop drown is selected above code will run. It will check both the dates are not empty then it will proceed. In next condition it will show an alert message if from_date is greater or equal than to_date.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){


  $('#from_date, #to_date').on('change', function(){


     var from_date =  $('#from_date').val();
     var to_date=  $('#to_date').val();

     // if both the fields are not empty
     if((Date.parse(from_date ) >= Date.parse(to_date))){

         alert("End date should be greater than Start date");
         //if End date is not value, deselect the selected date
         $('#to_date').val('');

         return false;
     }

  });// Change

});// Ready
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Start Date<br>
        <select id="from_date">
          <option> - select start of date - </option>
           <option value="2019-01-01"> 2019-01-01 </option>
           <option value="2019-01-15"> 2019-01-15 </option>
           <option value="2019-01-28"> 2019-01-28 </option>
        </select>
        
        
        <br><br>End Date<br>
        <select id="to_date">
          <option> - select end of date - </option>
           <option value="2017-08-29"> 2017-08-29 </option>
           <option value="2018-04-15"> 2018-04-15 </option>
           <option value="2019-05-17"> 2019-05-17 </option>
        </select>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for answering sir quick question. I tried it but it doesnt seem to work on me, probably my fault. I did "<select id="to_date" onchange="myfunction()" >" though im not  sure if i got the correct one on onchange because i added a function in the code you sent

Comment: I have added code snippet above, please use it instead of calling it on function, only you need to populate drop down options from your loop.

Answer (score 0):

It's sample, you can write a javascript code,convert datetime to timestamp,use timestamp to compare:

```
function a(fromDateTime,toDateTime){
    var fromTimestamp = new Date(fromDateTime).getTime()
    var toTimestamp = new Date(toDateTime).getTime()
    if (fromTimestamp > toTimestamp) {
        console.log("xxxxx")
        return
    }
}
```

when press commit button,call this function